# Export Form Data to a CSV then send it as an attachment - contact form 7

Tags: php, functions, plugin-contact-form-7

I want to export the form data and send it as an attachment. In this case, can i rewrite the file (/uploads/2020/08/sample.csv) with the form data and send it as an attachment.

right now, it is just a blank attachment when i receive it in my email

Here is my code in function.php, Please help me:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'add_form_as_attachment', 10, 1 ); 

function add_form_as_attachment(&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {
$contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
$Fname = $formdata['firstName'];
$Lname = $formdata['lastName'];
$email = $formdata['email'];

$list = array (
array( 'First Name:',$Fname),
array( 'Last Name:', $Lname),
array( 'Email:',  $email),

);

$fp = fopen( site_url() . 'uploads/2020/08/sample.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things omitted in the above solution, like defining the most params of wp_mail.
Also I didn't want to send yet another concurrent email, but instead attach the csv directly to the mail that wpcf7 sends. I think this is the cleaner solution.

Here's my take:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'add_form_as_attachment', 10, 3 );
function add_form_as_attachment( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {

    $form_id = $contact_form->id();

    //Check for selected form id and actual submission
    if ($form_id == 123 && $submission){

        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data() ;
        // Check again for posted data
        if ( empty ($posted_data)){
            return; 
        }

        //Get your form fields
        $firstname = $posted_data['your-name'];
        $lastname = $posted_data['your-lastname'];
        $email = $posted_data['your-email'];

        $list = array (
        array( 'First Name:',$firstname),
        array( 'Last Name:', $lastname),
        array( 'Email:',  $email),

        );
        // Save file path separately 
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
        $file_path = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/yourtempfolder/sample.csv'; // check File permission for writing content and remember to protect this folder from the public with htaccess for example

        $fp = fopen( $file_path , 'w'); //overwrites file at each submission
        foreach ($list as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);

        // Modification of mail(1) start here
        $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
        $properties['mail']['attachments'] = $file_path;
        $contact_form->set_properties($properties);

        return $contact_form;
    }//endif ID && submission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine problem with this code. Hope it could help others too -

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'add_form_as_attachment', 10, 1 ); 

function add_form_as_attachment(&$WPCF7_ContactForm) {
$contact_form = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
$Fname = $formdata['firstName'];
$Lname = $formdata['lastName'];
$email = $formdata['email'];

$list = array (
array( 'First Name:',$Fname),
array( 'Last Name:', $Lname),
array( 'Email:',  $email),

);
// Save file path separately 
$file_path = site_url() . 'uploads/2020/08/sample.csv'; // check File permission for writing content
$fp = fopen( $file_path , 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
//MAIL starts here 
$attachments = array( $file_path );
$headers = 'From: name <no-reply@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
 
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers, $attachments);
// You are done 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.. by the way where did you upload the 'uploads/2020/08/sample.csv' ? in media library ?

Comment: I have modified and used your code here. Well, it is better to upload things in Upload folder of WP. 
you can use following code also at place of 

***$file_path = site_url() . 'uploads/2020/08/sample.csv';***

You need to create a "temp" folder in "uploads" folder in wp-content ..  

`$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$file_path = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/temp/sample.csv';`

Comment: can i rename the attachment before sending it? something like "First_Name.csv"?

Comment: Off course you can keep name as per your requirement. As per my code "sample.csv" is a physical blank CSV file kept at the location mentioned. In same way you have to create a blank file and name whatever you want.

Comment: what about adding the other fields on another sheet? but same file..
inside sample.csv  there is sheet1 and sheet2

Comment: CSV doesn't have sheets. XLS or XLSX file format can have sheets.

Comment: i already solved this using csv

Comment: seems like the radio buttons and checkbox values are not inserting in csv